# Handling empty cell values in R for logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, missing-data

I have a csv file with a bunch of "empty cells" and a few missing values. I was able to impute the mean of the variable value to fill in the missing values. However, I'm unable to replace the empty cells with a certain text that I want to. I have been trying the same impute function to replace the empty cells but the output does not change. Appreciate any help. Thank you

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tLNs.png)
[variable output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jP31.png)

Comment: @mrVerma, I've pasted the csv file and the overview of one of the variables having the empty cell values. It looks like the empty value is more of "" than a NULL value. Therefore, I tried the 'sub' command to substitute those values with a letter but since all values have "" inbetween values, it's adding the letter to all values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to replace empty strings in a data frame column `col`:

```
df$col[df$col == ""] <- "whatever you want to put there"
```